# Redirect all HTTP and HTTPS request to a single HTTPS URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, centos7, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I want to redirect all HTTP and HTTPS requests to a single HTTPS URL, so the users only access the application through this URL.
Redirection of HTTP requests to HTTPS works but I'm struggling with the second part.

So far, my virtualhosts look like this :

```
<VirtualHost 10.201.100.81:80>
    ServerName sdvlirp
    ServerAlias sdvlirp.si.intra.net irp-dev
    <IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://irp-dev.intra.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.201.100.81:443>
    ServerName irp-dev.intra.net
    ErrorLog "logs/https_irp-dev.intra.net-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/https_irp-dev.intra.net-access_log" common

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
    SSLCompression Off
    SSLCertificateFile "/applis/irpdev/certs/irp-dev.intra.net.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/applis/irpdev/certs/irp-dev.intra.net.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/applis/irpdev/certs/cacerts.pem"
    Header Set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload;"

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>

    # SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    # The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    # approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    # the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    # approach you can use one of the following variables:
    # o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #   This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #   SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received. This violates
    #   the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #   this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #   mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    # o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #   This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #   SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #   alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #   practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #   this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #   works correctly.
    # Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    # keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    # keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    # Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    # their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    # "force-response-1.0" for this.
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    # Per-Server Logging:
    # The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    # compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    CustomLog "logs/ssl_request_log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

How would you do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is unclear, because if you redirect all of the traffic to one single URL, this means that you can't browse the website, but only this URL.

Your VirtualHost on port 80 is ok, but the RewriteRule is not redirecting to one single URL, but respectively it redirects one http URL to its https equivalent.
The VirtualHost on port 443 doesn't have any rewrite block. That's what you need to add if you want to also make https to https redirects.